# How to group my subtasks and add the values together

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this

```
array:5 [
  "Task 1" => array:4 [
    "SubTask 1" => 1.0
    "SubTask 2" => 4.0
    "SubTask 3" => 1.0
    "SubTask 4" => 1.0
  ]
  "Task 2" => array:3 [
    "SubTask 5" => 1.0
    "SubTask 6" => 1.0
    "SubTask 4" => 1.0
  ]
  "Task 3" => array:3 [
    "SubTask" => 5.0
    "SubTask 6" => 1.0
    "SubTask 5" => 1.0
  ]
  "Task 4" => array:2 [
    "SubTask 6" => 1.0
    "SubTask 7" => 1.0
  ]
  "Task 5" => array:3 [
    "SubTask 1" => 1.0
    "SubTask 6" => 1.0
    "SubTask 7" => 1.0
  ]
]
```

What I would like is is to be able to group the subtasks together and calculate the hours.

Here is my code

```
$subTaskArr = [];

foreach($projects as $projectCode => $project)
{
    foreach($project->getTasks() as $taskKey => $taskValue)
    {
        $testArr = [];
        foreach($taskValue->getWorkers() as $workerKey  => $workerValue)
        {
            $testArr[$workerKey] = $workerValue->getHours();
        }
    }
    $subTaskArr[$projectCode] = $testArr;
}

dd($subTaskArr);
```

I'm not sure how and what would be the best approach to solve this.

Comment: Are your subtasks not already grouped by task number?  How would you like to group them?

Answer (score 0):

Through the array you can group like this

```
$SubTask = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
     foreach($val as $index=>$value){
        if(!(isset($SubTask[$index]))) $SubTask[$index] = 0;
        $SubTask[$index] += floatval($value);
     }
}

print_r($SubTask);

//****
  Output

  Array
  (
    [SubTask 1] => 2
    [SubTask 2] => 4
    [SubTask 3] => 1
    [SubTask 4] => 2
    [SubTask 5] => 2
    [SubTask 6] => 4
    [SubTask] => 5
    [SubTask 7] => 2
  )
*****//
```

Comment: check now please !!